# How to generate table contents based on contents from other tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have many-to-many relationship and 3 tables: A, B, C.

A and C each have only 1 primary key and B has compound primary key being foreign keys to tables A and C and nothing more.

Tables A and C are already filled with data and each of them has 100 rows and now I would like to insert a row to B consisting of random key from A and random key from C. How to achieve that?

This is what I tried but I don't know how to get currently processed row in select statement and I'm stuck now... I don't even know if this kind of statement is actually alright or there's better approach?

```
INSERT INTO B(bKey1, bKey2) 
VALUES(
(select a.key1 from A a where Convert(int, rand() * 100.0) = currentRow? ),
 (select c.key2 from C c where Convert(int, rand() * 100.0) = currentRow? )
 );
```

Even after inserting fixed value as 1 or 2 instead of "currentRow?" I'm getting following errors and don't understand why:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'bKey1', table 'MyDataBase.dbo.B'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I would be really grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a random record from each table, you can `cross join` the tables together, use `top 1`, and order by `newid()`:

```
INSERT INTO B(bKey1, bKey2) 
    select top 1
        a.key1,
        c.key2
    from A a
        cross join C c
    order by newid()
```

Comment: Works great, Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. I like this better than using `rand()` because you can insert numerous random records using `top n` and the cross join won't include any repeats. `Rand()` forces you to loop through the insert for multiple records and can repeat the same values selected previously.